How to conditionally render the multiple attribute in mat-select based on a form control value in Angular?
I have a form in my Angular application with a mat-select element that should allow multiple selections based on a condition. Specifically, I want to conditionally include the multiple attribute on the mat-select based on the value of a form control.
Here's the code snippet for the mat-select:
<mat-select formControlName="queries" [multiple]="ticketForm.get('queryType')?.value === 'Service Request'">
  <!-- Your options here -->
</mat-select>

However, when I try to use this approach, the multiple attribute is not rendered correctly.
What is the correct way to conditionally include the multiple attribute in a mat-select element in Angular based on the value of a form control?
i also tried using Angular attribute binding, suggested from chatGPT
 <mat-select
        formControlName="queries"
        [attr.multiple]="
          ticketForm.get('queryType')?.value == 'Service Request' ? true : true
        "
      >

but here too the multiple attribute is not working,

This is by design: https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#error-cannot-change-multiple-mode-of-select-after-initialization.
You should use two separate <mat-select> elements, as suggested in the docs.

We have to create then destroy the element, before modifying the multiple attribute, since angular gives me the below error!

ERROR Error: Cannot change multiple mode of select after initialization.

  toggleMultiple() {
    // we must reset the value, since we are changing the mode!
    this.toppings.reset();
    this.toggleSelect = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.multiple = !this.multiple;
      this.toggleSelect = true;
    });
  }

FULL CODE:
TS:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { NgIf } from '@angular/common';

/** @title Select with multiple selection */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-multiple-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-multiple-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgIf,
  ],
})
export class SelectMultipleExample {
  multiple = true;
  toggleSelect = true;
  toppings = new FormControl('');
  toppingList: string[] = [
    'Extra cheese',
    'Mushroom',
    'Onion',
    'Pepperoni',
    'Sausage',
    'Tomato',
  ];

  toggleMultiple() {
    // we must reset the value, since we are changing the mode!
    this.toppings.reset();
    this.toggleSelect = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.multiple = !this.multiple;
      this.toggleSelect = true;
    });
  }
}

HTML:
<mat-form-field *ngIf="toggleSelect">
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" [multiple]="multiple">
    @for (topping of toppingList; track topping) {
    <mat-option [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
    }
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<br />
multiple: {{multiple}}<br />
<button (click)="toggleMultiple()">Toggle Multiple</button>
<br /><br />
{{toppings.value}}

Stackblitz Demo

1- Define a method in your component class to evaluate the condition.
2- Bind the multiple attribute to that method in your template.
export class MyComponent {
  ticketForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.ticketForm = this.fb.group({
      queries: [''],
      queryType: ['']
    });
  }

  isMultipleSelect(): boolean {
    return this.ticketForm.get('queryType')?.value === 'Service Request';
  }
}
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Queries</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="queries" [multiple]="isMultipleSelect()">
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option2">Option 2</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>


This just moves the functionality from the template to the component. It changes nothing about the fact that multiple of mat-select cannot be changed after initialization, as per docs.
